# How Spark Structured Streaming handles backpressure?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, backpressure

I'm analyzing the backpressure feature on Spark Structured Streaming. Does anyone know the details? Is it possible to tune process incoming records by code?
Thanks

Comment: How would you define a backpressure?

Comment: I mean, the feature to dynamically manage the ingestion rate for the records. On Spark Streaming can be activated and you can work on kafka.maxRatePerPartition, if you use Kafka. And how about Structured Streaming? How does it work internally? Is it manageable by the programmer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you mean dynamically changing the size of each internal batch in Structured Streaming, then **NO**. There are not receiver-based sources in Structured Streaming, so that's totally not necessary. From another point of view, Structured Streaming cannot do real backpressure, because, such as, Spark cannot tell other applications to slow down the speed of pushing data into Kafka.

Generally, Structured Streaming will try to process data as fast as possible by default. There are options in each source to allow to control the processing rate, such as `maxFilesPerTrigger` in File source, and `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` in Kafka source. Read the following links for more details:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Answer (score 4):

Handling back pressure is needed only is push based mechanisms. Kafka consumers are pull based, spark will pull next batch of records only when current batch is finished processing and saving. If processing & saving is delayed in spark, it won't pull new batch of records so no need of back pressure handling.

[maxOffsetsPerTrigger](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#maxOffsetsPerTrigger) can change the number of records processed per spark batch set, [backpressure.enabled](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-streaming) changes rate of receiving, but that's not same as back pressure where you go and tell the source to slow dow.

Comment: Then how come spark streaming (non-structured) has back pressure property? Do you mean to say it is push based? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#requirements

Comment: Kafka supports only pull based consumption https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586635/why-is-kafka-pull-based-instead-of-push-based . So it's always pull irrespective of structured or non-structured streaming.