# confluent kafka - Rate limiting

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Rate limiting: As Kafka is able to generate messages at a much higher rate than MQ can consume, can we have some configuration setup @ kafka consumer to to enable a rate-limiting transfer to protect the stability of MQ?

Also Exactly-Once Semantic - Understand that kafka supports exactly-once semantics which would stop the retransfer of messages that have already been consumed by consumers. Can someone guide me on how to setup this configuration?

we are using confluent kafka enterprise version in our organization.

Answer (score 0):

*Rate limiting:* Kafka is [**pull**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586635/why-is-kafka-pull-based-instead-of-push-based) based so your consumer could read messages at an own peace and transfer them into MQ (but if the second system is constantly slower, the buffer of unprocessed message in Kafka will increase though the time).

*Exactly once semantic:* to ensure [exactly once sematic](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) for consumer you need to commit read offset manually once the message is successfully processed (the default behavior is automatic commit of read offset after small timeout. It could lead to lost of the message, if the fail happens after commit of read offset but before end of the processing of the message)